# One-liner to set a variable value with signal handler function in response to a signal from GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

No, question's **not duplicate**. It isn't about "How to say `a=1` in python"?

And **isn't trivial**. Please read carefully.

**Answer is**: **it's impossible** to create such a one-liner, at least without using dirty hacks. See the accepted answer for details.

And if you don't want to read, but came here for easy karma, please pass by and stop minusing me, cause the accepted answer is very useful. :)

---

Question:

I'm doing some GUI programming and want to create a very short signal handler that would set local variable to a value in response to a signal from GUI.

```
def function():
    output = False #this is local variable; I want to change its value by signal handler
    button = PyQt4.QtGui.QPushButton("simple button")
    #next line sets output to True
    button.pressed.connect(lambda:SOME_FUNCTION_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR(output, True))
    #Now output==True
```

Could you suggest, what to substitute for `SOME_FUNCTION_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR`? Obviously, you can't just say `button.pressed.connect(output=True)`, cause `output=True` isn't a function.

To illustrate what I'm looking for here's an analogue: if you want to set an object's attribute, you can use `setattr` function. Here's an analogue of code above, setting attribute instead of local variable:

```
def function():
    ...
    #create a dummy UserObject class and make an instance of it to store attributes
    output_object = type('UserObject', (), {})() 
    output_object.it_was_pressed = False #flags that button was pressed
    #when "pressed" signal of button is emitted, "it_was_pressed" attribute of output_object is set to True
    button = PyQt4.QtGui.QPushButton("simple button")
    button.pressed.connect(lambda: setattr(output_object, "it_was_pressed", True)
```

That's **not** what I want to do. What I want to do is create an analogue of this to set a local variable in response to signal:

**UPDATE:**

I'm asking for **one-liner** solution: concise and elegant. Of course, I could do this in 3 lines, but I don't want to.

Comment: Also read: [How do I write a function with output parameters (call by reference)?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)

Comment: either use a global variable, or pass ```self``` if it is inside a class already.

Comment: @delnan not exactly, question is more specifically related to callback functionality, IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** *reliable* way to modify the local environment "programmatically" (i.e. without an explicit assignment).

For example this works in python2:

```
>>> def test():
...     output = False
...     exec('output=True')
...     print(output)
... 
>>> test()
True
>>> test()
True
```

However it does *not* work in python3!

```
>>> def test():
...     output = False
...     exec('output=True')
...     print(output)
... 
>>> test()
False
```

Modifying the dictionary returned by [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) might not work, for example:

```
>>> def test():   #python 2 and 3
...     output = False
...     locals()['output'] = True
...     print(output)
... 
>>> test()
False
```

<sup>It might work on some old versions of python.</sup>

`exec` probably works in python2 because it is a statement, hence the python compiler can determine if the function might need to really use a `dict` to store its variables and make `exec` work properly`. It's pretty simple to check this:

```
>>> def test():
...     exec('pass')
...     locals()['output'] = True
...     print(output)
... 
>>> test()
True
>>> def test():
...     locals()['output'] = True
...     print(output)
... 
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in test
NameError: global name 'output' is not defined
```

As you can see if a function contains an `exec` statement python avoids to optimize local variables and just uses the `dict` (thus making changes to `locals()` work properly). When no `exec` is found changes don't work.

In python3 `exec` *is* a function and the python compiler always optimizes local lookup.

---

So:

- in python2 you could do that with `exec`, but it is a statement and cannot be used inside `lambda`s
- in python3 you simply *cannot* do what you want, no matter how hard you try. There is simply *no* way to modify a local variable *without* an explicit assignment statement.

Therefore what you ask is, AFAIK, impossible to do in a single *expression* of one line (at least in any reasonably readable way). The *proper* way of doing what you want is to use `nonlocal` in python3:

```
output = False
def handler():
    nonlocal output
    output = True

button.pressed.connect(handler)
```

In python2 you don't even have `nonlocal` so you'll have to use one of the hacks to work around this (like putting in `output` a one element list etc.).

I don't exclude that there exist a *ugly*, *unreadable* and *hackish* way of writing a one-liner that defines a function (not a `lambda`!) and that achieves what you want, but I'm pretty sure there is *no*  "concise and elegant" one-liner that does what you want.

---

Obviously if you don't mind `output` to be a list you could do the ugly:

```
output = [False]

button.pressed.connect(lambda: output.__setitem__(0, True))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to read into the question and to write a whole survey! I'll let the question hang for a while, may be someone suggests an `ugly, unreadable and hackish way` (just for the sake of interest), but will nevertheless accept your answer later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about the boolean check, you can rely on some Pythonic idioms:

```
output = {} # similar to False case

def callback_func(output, val):
    if val:
       output['set']=True
    else:
       output.clear()
```

If dictionary is empty it will be evaluated as False, otherwise as true.

Comment: I worry about shortness: your callback function is 5 lines long. I'd accept a 1-line lambda function :) Note that in the second code snippet output is a variable, not an object. I want to set `output = True`, not `output.attribute = True`.

More generally, I want a function, analogous to `exec "output=1"`, like exec("a=1"), if exec were a function like `eval`.